# SQL: how to SELECT strings and INSERT INTO a new table

Tags: mysql

trying to select certain meta key / values from a wordpress table and insert them into a new table.  However, the targeted meta value is a string, and the below query only copies the first word of the "employer_address".

Can I modify this to copy the entire selected string to the new table?

```
INSERT INTO post_addresses (id, address)
SELECT post_id, meta_value
FROM wordpress_postmeta
WHERE meta_key = 'employer_address'
```

Comment: This query will copy everything post_id, meta_value has into the post_addresses. But if it is not copying the entire data, it could mean that the column in post_addreses table have length smaller than meta_value. Depending on your SQL mode this could return an error or a warning. Can you show us the results of show create table ?

Comment: @Mike You are absolutely correct - the issue was that the receiving table was not the correct data type to accept the full string.  I changed the type VARCHAR and the query above now works.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Assuming post_id is for id and meta_value is for address,

```
INSERT INTO post_addresses(id, address) 
VALUES(
       (SELECT post_id FROM wordpress_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'employer_address'),
       (SELECT meta_value FROM wordpress_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'employer_address')
   )
```

Comment: If the syntax are correct here. This query is the same as the one in the answer but slower.

Answer (score 0):

@Mike You are absolutely correct - the issue was that the receiving table was not the correct data type to accept the full string. I changed the type VARCHAR and the query above now works. –  David B just now   edit

Comment: I just made my comment an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

This query will copy everything post_id, meta_value has into the post_addresses.

But if it is not copying the entire data, it could mean that the column in post_addreses table have length smaller than meta_value. Depending on your SQL mode this could return an error or a warning.